# How do I generate URDFs at compile time?

Tags: urdf, cmake, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I sometime use robots definitions containing many links and generating the URDFs from my XACROs files takes more than 5 seconds.
This slows down my application startup because everything is waiting for XACRO to finish it's job.

Instead of generating the URDF with XACRO at run-time (in the launch file) I would like to generate them at compile time, ideally only when needed (= a modification has been done).

How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254974/how-do-i-generate-urdfs-at-compile-time?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### **UPDATE**

As Gijs pointed out, there is already a CMake macro for that:
http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Building_from_CMakeLists.txt

The macro is here:
https://github.com/ros/xacro/blob/kinetic-devel/cmake/

---

It is possible to generate URDF files at compile time thanks to the `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` CMake commands.

### In short

- Create a custom command that generates URDF files from XACRO files
- Create a target depending on all your URDF files and that depends on every target of you CMake script

### Details

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/urdf/robot.urdf
  DEPENDS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/urdf/box_line_macro.xacro
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/urdf/box_macro.xacro
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/urdf/robot.xacro
  COMMAND
  xacro --inorder robot.xacro -o robot.urdf
  WORKING_DIRECTORY
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/urdf/
  COMMENT
  "Generating ${PROJECT_NAME} robot URDF"
  VERBATIM
)
```

This creates a command that will generate your URDF file, using `DEPENDS` makes sure that everytime one of the XACRO file is changed the URDF will be generated.
This means that URDFs are generated only if necessary as long as you list all dependencies correctly. You can multiply this command block to generate multiple URDF files.

```
add_custom_target(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}_URDFs_files
  ALL
  DEPENDS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/urdf/robot.urdf
)
```

This command creates a CMake target that is built when "make all" is invoked and that depends on the URDF files. This ensures that the custom command will be called.
You should list here all your generated URDF files.

In your launch file instead of something like:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find xacro_urdf_cmake)/urdf/robot.xacro" />
```

You now should use:

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find xacro_urdf_cmake)/urdf/robot.urdf" />
```

Instead of generating the URDF at run-time (in the launch file), you can now use the URDF generated at compile time.

### Caveats

- It does not work if your xacro files have `($find xacro_urdf_cmake)` because `xacro` is invoked by CMake and does not source the workspace you are working in. Use relative paths!
- If you are writing some tests, you must manually specify that your test depends on the `${PROJECT_NAME}_URDFs_files` target
- URDFs are generated in the source package, you should ignore them with a `.gitignore` file

A demonstration package is available at [xacro_urdf_cmake](https://gitlab.com/VictorLamoine/xacro_urdf_cmake). Checkout the [pipeline](https://gitlab.com/VictorLamoine/xacro_urdf_cmake/pipelines) to see what is does!

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-18**:
This does look a bit like a 'duplicate' of [wiki/xacro - Building from CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Building_from_CMakeLists.txt)?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-02-22**:
Oh yes it is! I wish I had found this while searching. I'll improve the macro with a PR is needed. Thanks for the link